# Use range channel in go error fatal

Tags: go

I am coding the [golang tour execise](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/8). I can get all the value from channel with `for i := 0 i < 10; i++`. But get fatal with `for v := range`.

```
package main

import (
  "golang.org/x/tour/tree"
  "fmt"
)

// Walk walks the tree t sending all values
// from the tree to the channel ch.
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
  if t.Left != nil {
    // Walk left tree
    Walk(t.Left, ch)
  }

  ch <- t.Value

  if t.Right != nil {
    // Walk right tree
    Walk(t.Right, ch)
  }
}

func main() {
  ch := make(chan int)

  go Walk(tree.New(5), ch)

  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
  }
}
```

The output is right. It is 5, 10, 15 ... 50.

When I use the `for v := range ch`. It error falal.

```
func main() {
  ch := make(chan int)

  go Walk(tree.New(5), ch)

  for v := range ch {
    fmt.Println(v)
  }
}
```

The output is the following. I think it is related I don't close the ch.

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
```

Comment: You're not closing the `ch` channel

Comment: The `Walk` is recursive. It seems I can't `close(ch)` inside `Walk`.

Comment: so close it outside of Walk. https://play.golang.org/p/xCWBf9BA6y